# Django serving static files locally

Tags: django

It's been a while since I've setup django to work locally. I'm using version `1.11`. Getting it to serve the static files.
My project is called `chatsys` and I've created the static folder and css in this folder `chatsys\static\css\style.css` .

Here's the current settings in the settings file.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

and in the urls

```
#for serving static files
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and finally in the html

```
{% load static %}
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">
```

however in the runserver console I get 404 for `/static/css/style.css`

Comment: Are you running in development with `DEBUG=True`? Where is the `style.css` file located? If you print/log `STATIC_ROOT`, does it give you the correct location?

Comment: yes, debug = True and the css file is located in chatsys\static\css\style.css which is in the main directory. Printing the path looks ok... it's `<full_path>\chatsys\static`

Comment: I'm still not completely clear on your project layout. Is the `STATIC_ROOT` in the project directory (the one containing `manage.py`) or the inner directory (the one containing `settings.py`)? Your `STATIC_ROOT` is set up for the first case.

Comment: in the project directory containing manage.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) and include your project's static directory there.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

These are the directories that Django collects static files from.

You should then change [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#static-root) to be a different directory. It is the directory that `collectstatic` collects static files to. The static root should not be under version control.

As an aside, you are loading the static tag in your template but not using it. You could change it to:

```
{% load static %}
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

Comment: on point, you nailed it :) I'll stick to not using `load static` I was trying to use it to debug and see if that would fix it.

Comment: At the moment, it doesn't really matter whether you use `{% static %}` or hardcode `/static/`. But if you change `STATIC_URL` in future (e.g. to use a CDN) then you won't have to update all your templates if you used `{% static %}`.

Comment: I know, and its just for a project trying to see if I can make a chatting sys so likely won't be hosted. And good thing still is I tend to use the same path in nginx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Move your static folder under the base dir

- chatsys

  - migrations
  - templates
  - etc.
- static

  - css

    - style.css

Comment: Could you please try to remove `{% load static %}` ?

Comment: tried it, didn't work. it's part of the configuration that has an issue.

Comment: After the `STATIC_ROOT` try to add this line `STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_ROOT, 
]` .