# Django 2.0.4 not serving style.css

Tags: css, django

I am trying to load some static files in Django 2.0.4:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
```

the jquery file loads fine, but the css results in a 404.

Why?

I have tried running python manage.py collectstatic, but I don't think it is picking up the css file for some reason..

Comment: Please show the layout of your project including the static directory. Are you running in development with `DEBUG=True` or is this happening in production?

Comment: In settings.py I have 
STATIC_URL = '/media/' STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') and within media i have js/jquery.js from django-jquery and I manually added css/style.css. Also this is with runserver (DEBUG=true)

Comment: My answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49874319/django-serving-static-files-locally) might help you. Also, I would recommend that you use a different name than `media`. You don't want to confuse static files (js/images/css checked in to your repo) with media files (uploaded by users, not checked in).

Comment: ah ok, thanks. So STATICFILES_DIRS is for my hand-coded css and js and STATIC_ROOT is for collectstatic to dump the generic jquery/bootstrap etc libraries?

Comment: Almost. `STATICFILES_DIRS` is for your handcoded css and also your css/js libraries. `STATIC_ROOT` is where all of those files are collected to.